# iif statement do nothing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, report

I am trying to return nothing for a false statement. Is there a way to do this?

`iif(a=1, "Yes", null)` <--- this obviously didn't work, but is there anything else that returns nothing if it evaluates a statement as false?

Comment: Please read [What is the X Y Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/102937)

Answer (score 5):

If this is in an SSRS expression then you can use the following

```
=IIF(Fields!myField.Value = 1, "Yes", nothing)
```

`nothing` in SSRS expressions is similar to `NULL`

*For example you can set a textbox background color to `nothing` which is the same as selecting 'no color' on the property drop down.*